# Não aparece o conteúdo do campo na Dbgrid

Tags: delphi

Em uma dbgrid, quero que apareça alguns campos da tabela contas a pagar e o campo `vlparcela_parcelasapagar` da tabela parcelas a pagar..

Portanto fiz um join nas duas tabelas, veja o exemplo:

```
SELECT p.*
      ,c.fan_clifor
      ,pp.vlparcela_parcelasapagar
  FROM contasapagar p, 1parcelasapagar pp, cli_for c, cademp e
 WHERE p.cdconta_contasapagar = pp.cdconta_contasapagar
   AND p.cod_clifor           = c.cod_clifor
   AND p.cod_emp              = e.cod_emp
   AND c.tipo_clifor          = 'F'
```

Após eu salvar usando o método POST do `TClientDataset` e Commit não aparece o valor da parcela do campo `vlparcela_parcelasapagar` na dbgrid.

Eu tenho que fechar a tela do contas a pagar e reabrir ela, então mostra o valor...

Como faço para que no momento que eu salvo ele mostra o valor do campo parcelas a pagar???

Para mostrar na grid estou usando o TClientDataset...
Quando eu salvo, após usar o comando POST, coloquei um refresh e também coloquei assim(mas não adiantou...):

```
cds.Close; 
cds.Open;
```

Como poderia fazer? Neste caso tem solução??

> Estou usando o Delphi 2010, dbexpress e Firebird 2.0

Comment: Amigo, não entendi alguns pontos. Como você passa o retorno do SQL para o ClientDataSet? Por um DataSetProvider? Ou vai fazendo *Append's* dentro dum *while*?

Comment: O retorno do SQL para o ClientDataset eu uso o Datasetprovider...

Comment: Para Salvar o registro faço  assim:

Comment: Cds.edit; Cds.post;Cds.applyupdates(-1)

Answer (score 0):

Simples, após salvar dê o **SELECT** novamente utilizando o seu clientDataset, que o dbgrid com certeza será utilizado.

Quando você fecha a tela e abre novamente os valores aparecem, por que você deu um SELECT no evento onShow ou onActive